# Passing the carousel items to a Map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, ecmascript-6

I have a issue regarding how to map items properly into Bootstrap carousel, to this moment I have tried this, but result is one picture below another, not showing as carousel.
In this project I want to use React with Bootstrap, without using another Carousel packages.

**JSX CODE:**

```js
export default class Carousel extends Component {
  render() {
    const slides = data.slides;
    return (
      <div
        id='carouselExampleInterval'
        className='carousel slide'
        data-ride='carousel'
      >
        <div className='carousel-inner'>
          {slides.map((slide, i) => (
            <div
              key={i}
              active={i === 0}
              className={'carousel item' + this.props.active ? ' active' : ''}
              data-interval='8000'
            >
              <img
                src={slide.url}
                className='d-block w-100'
                alt={slide.title}
              />
              <div className='carousel-caption d-none d-md-block'>
                <h5 className=''>{slide.title}</h5>
                <p>{slide.subtitle}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>

        <a
          className='carousel-control-prev'
          href='#carouselExampleInterval'
          role='button'
          data-slide='prev'
        >
          <span
            className='carousel-control-prev-icon'
            aria-hidden='true'
          ></span>
          <span className='sr-only'>Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a
          className='carousel-control-next'
          href='#carouselExampleInterval'
          role='button'
          data-slide='next'
        >
          <span
            className='carousel-control-next-icon'
            aria-hidden='true'
          ></span>
          <span className='sr-only'>Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Any ideas as to how to fix this issue?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

```
export default class Carousel extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        isActive:"carousel-item active",
        nActive:"carousel-item"
    }
}
render() {
const {isActive,nActive}=this.state;
const slides = data.slides;
return (
  <div
    id='carouselExampleInterval'
    className='carousel slide'
    data-ride='carousel'
  >
    <div className='carousel-inner'>
      {slides.map((slide, i) => (
        <div
          key={i}
          active={i === 0}
          className={index===0 ? isActive:nActive}
          data-interval='8000'
        >
          <img
            src={slide.url}
            className='d-block w-100'
            alt={slide.title}
          />
          <div className='carousel-caption d-none d-md-block'>
            <h5 className=''>{slide.title}</h5>
            <p>{slide.subtitle}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>

    <a
      className='carousel-control-prev'
      href='#carouselExampleInterval'
      role='button'
      data-slide='prev'
    >
      <span
        className='carousel-control-prev-icon'
        aria-hidden='true'
      ></span>
      <span className='sr-only'>Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a
      className='carousel-control-next'
      href='#carouselExampleInterval'
      role='button'
      data-slide='next'
    >
      <span
        className='carousel-control-next-icon'
        aria-hidden='true'
      ></span>
      <span className='sr-only'>Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 1):

In the carousel, if we wanted to implement mapping functionality especially in react js, then we need to use npm's reactstrap plugin.

[See here for more information on react's carousel](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/carousel/)

Comment: Kiran,

Any idea how to make the carousel text not hide automatically on mobile?